# Is numba efficient for numpy.linalg.inv?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, matrix-inverse

I am trying to use `numpy.linalg.inv` in some code which is then jitted with `@numba.njit`. However, I notice that the code does not get significantly faster. Moreover, when I run the same code several times, the time varies drastically (like 4 times different). I wrote some toy code to check whether `numpy.linalg.inv` gets faster at all with numba:

```
    def matrinv(M):
        res = np.linalg.inv(M)
        return res

    @njit
    def matrinv_fast(M):
        res = np.linalg.inv(M)
        return res
```

The running times are almost the same (like 40 ms vs 35 ms). Is it because the existing numpy functions are already precompiled, and numba cannot get them faster? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: NumPy functions already drop down to optimized C code. Numba can't make significant improvements on that. Numba is very useful for optimizing a subset of pure Python, especially loops, close to the performance of optimized C code.

Comment: Since you are inverting a matrix, here is the obligatory reminder that you probably shouldn't.
http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/12/09/matrix-inversion/
TLDR: There are almost always better approaches than inverting a matrix, e.g. np.linalg.solve